# Configure GCC for optimization

Tags: optimization, gcc

I trying to build gcc such that we can perform the highest optimization on an Intel E5-2690 x86_64. The default gcc is configured with :

```
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-redhat-linux
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla --enable-bootstrap --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-checking=release --disable-build-with-cxx --disable-build-poststage1-with-cxx --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-linker-build-id --with-linker-hash-style=gnu --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,java,fortran,ada,go,lto --enable-plugin --enable-initfini-array --enable-java-awt=gtk --disable-dssi --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-1.5.0.0/jre --enable-libgcj-multifile --enable-java-maintainer-mode --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --disable-libjava-multilib --with-ppl --with-cloog --with-tune=generic --with-arch_32=i686 --build=x86_64-redhat-linux
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.7.2 20121109 (Red Hat 4.7.2-8) (GCC)
```

I have the svn gnu gcc checkout in `/apps/gnugcc` and binutils in `/apps/binutils`.
I can experiment with the options but I don't have depth of knowledge here to select teh best optimizations and how to set architecture etc.

Comment: You don't need to build GCC itself with architecture-specific optimizations in order for it to generate architecture-specific optimized code.